# Using gRPC with gevent

Tags: python, timeout, grpc, gevent

I am using gRPC in a gevent monkey patched environment and I am seeing deadline exceeded for a deadline of 500ms. But the service responds in < 40ms. I am assuming this is due to the use of gevent, messing up the timing. But now where I have applied:

```
import grpc.experimental.gevent as grpc_gevent
grpc_gevent.init_gevent()
```

I am seeing `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` even in my integration test.

Comment: Any more information? If you up the timeout of 500ms to something more lenient, does it succeed?

Answer (score 4):

I'm having the same problem. After looking at `init_gevent`, I found a sentence:

> This must be called AFTER the python standard lib has been patched,
> but BEFORE creating and gRPC objects.

Try adding the import at the top:

```py
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import grpc._cython.cygrpc
grpc._cython.cygrpc.init_grpc_gevent()
```

ref : https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/14561#issue-301487490

Comment: Please [edit] and clarify what sets your answer apart from the other answer. If the explanation is in the link, outline its content.